# MySQL statement in SQLAlchemy

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlalchemy, subquery

How can I write this statement in SQLAlchemy?

```
SELECT post_id, forum_id, topic_id
FROM posts p
WHERE post_time =
  (SELECT max(post_time) FROM posts p2
   WHERE p2.topic_id = p.topic_id
   AND p2.forum_id = p.forum_id)
GROUP BY forum_id, topic_id, post_id
ORDER BY post_time DESC
```

Comment: Look at subqueries. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#using-subqueries

Comment: looks like what I was looking for, you can answer and I will mark as resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subqueries are what you are looking for.

http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/tutorial.html#using-subqueries